# SQLExpress instance is definitely running but can not connect IntelliJ DB Navigator

Tags: intellij-idea, sql-server-express

I have SQLExpress installed and running and have created a database called "test".

Using SQL Server Management Studio I am able to connect and carry out all operations:

[image]

However when I try and connect via the DB Navigator in IntelliJ it's giving me a connection timeout error. I've tried various connection values but I thought it would be as simple as this:

[image]

I have noticed that if I try and connect on port 1433 the error wording is "Communication timeout" and if I try on another port it's "The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.". So I feel like there is something being recognised on that port.

I can't move on with my project until I can verify that my server is accepting connections, does anyone have any suggestions for troubleshooting?

- Using SQL Server Configuration Manager I have verified that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled and I have set the port to 1433.
- I have SQL Server Browser service running.
- I have tried the built in IntelliJ driver and I have also provided the Microsoft JDBC Driver, but this makes no difference.
- I have tried disabling Windows Firewall but it made no difference.

Comment: Could you please try "Database Tools and SQL" plugin instead of custom DBNavigator?

Comment: Why does "Host" say `localhost` instead of `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` or match exactly the name you use for SSMS? The tool is possibly ignoring the port and looking for a default instance (but I've never used that and you'd have to verify from the vendor).

Comment: @y.bedrov unfortunately that is only available with IntelliJ Ultimate and not Community Edition

I think I am going to try and find a way to ditch DBNavigator and do this connection with Database Tools and SQL which should allow me to supply the same path.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have tried with the same path as SSMS but it gives a message "Invalid or incomplete database configuration: - Database information incomplete or invalid (host, port, database, file)"

I think I am going to try and find a way to ditch DBNavigator and do this connection with Database Tools and SQL which should allow me to supply the same path.

Comment: You may check it with Ultimate Edition with Evaluation period.